# Numerology Calculator

Tags: code-golf

The goal of this challenge is to compute *one kind of* numerology digit from strings containing characters and numbers.

- The input may be through any convenient method (standard input, arguments, separated file).
- The input may contain any printable ASCII chars, but only alphanumerical (`A-Z`, `a-z`, and `0-9`) have to be considered.
- The output must be a digit between `1` and `9` or a star `*` if no letter and no digit where found... (or even `0` if input contain any number of `0` *and* nothing else but this doesn't matter).
- Letter values are mapped in this way:

  ```
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i
  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r
  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
  ```
- The *numerology digit* is computed by adding each value of string, then repeat until there is only one digit. Sample for `13579`, `Hello, world!`, `00 0 00`, `!@#$%^&*();`,  and `3.141592`:

  ```
  13579 => 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 = 25 => 2 + 5 = 7
  Hello, world! => 8 + 5 + 3 + 3 + 6 + 5 + 6 + 9 + 3 + 4 = 52 => 5 + 2 = 7
  00 0 00 => 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 0
  !@#$%^&*(); => *
    => *
  3.141592 => 3 + 1 + 4 + 1 + 5 + 9 + 2 = 25 => 2 + 5 = 7
  3.1415926535897932384 => 
   3 + 1 + 4 + 1 + 5 + 9 + 2 + 6 + 5 + 3 + 5 + 8 + 9 + 7 + 9 + 3 + 2 + 3 + 8 + 4
   = 97 => 9 + 7 = 16 => 1 + 6 = 7
  ```

  (This is great, most of this samples give `7`! But it's just sample ;)

  Some more tests:

  ```
  Bob  => 2 + 6 + 2 = 10 => 1 + 0 = 1
  Charlie => 3 + 8 + 1 + 9 + 3 + 9 + 5 = 38 => 3 + 8 = 11 => 1 + 1 = 2
  Anna => 1 + 5 + 5 + 1 = 12 => 1 + 2 = 3
  Fana => 6 + 1 + 5 + 1 = 13 => 1 + 3 = 4
  Gregory => 7 + 9 + 5 + 7 + 6 + 9 + 7 = 50 => 5 + 0 = 5
  Denis => 4 + 5 + 5 + 9 + 1 = 24 => 2 + 4 = 6
  Erik => 5 + 9 + 9 + 2 = 25 => 2 + 5 = 7
  Helen => 8 + 5 + 3 + 5 + 5 = 26 => 2 + 6 = 8
  Izis => 9 + 8 + 9 + 1 = 27 => 2 + 7 = 9
  ```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

#### Shortest by language

```html
<style>body { text-align: left !important} #answer-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } #language-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } table thead { font-weight: bold; } table td { padding: 5px; }</style><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table><script>var QUESTION_ID = document.referrer.split("/")[4]; var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe"; var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk"; var OVERRIDE_USER = 0; var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page; function answersUrl(index) { return "//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" + QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER; } function commentUrl(index, answers) { return "//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER; } function getAnswers() { jQuery.ajax({ url: answersUrl(answer_page++), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { answers.push.apply(answers, data.items); answers_hash = []; answer_ids = []; data.items.forEach(function(a) { a.comments = []; var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/); answer_ids.push(id); answers_hash[id] = a; }); if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false; comment_page = 1; getComments(); } }); } function getComments() { jQuery.ajax({ url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { data.items.forEach(function(c) { if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER) answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c); }); if (data.has_more) getComments(); else if (more_answers) getAnswers(); else process(); } }); } getAnswers(); var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/; var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i; function getAuthorName(a) { return a.owner.display_name; } function process() { var valid = []; answers.forEach(function(a) { var body = a.body; a.comments.forEach(function(c) { if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body)) body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>'; }); var match = body.match(SCORE_REG); if (match) valid.push({ user: getAuthorName(a), size: +match[2], language: match[1], link: a.share_link, }); else console.log(body); }); valid.sort(function (a, b) { var aB = a.size, bB = b.size; return aB - bB }); var languages = {}; var place = 1; var lastSize = null; var lastPlace = 1; valid.forEach(function (a) { if (a.size != lastSize) lastPlace = place; lastSize = a.size; ++place; var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html(); answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".") .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user) .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language) .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link); answer = jQuery(answer); jQuery("#answers").append(answer); var lang = a.language; lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text(); languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang.toLowerCase(42), user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link}; }); var langs = []; for (var lang in languages) if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang)) langs.push(languages[lang]); langs.sort(function (a, b) { if (a.lang_raw > b.lang_raw) return 1; if (a.lang_raw < b.lang_raw) return -1; return 0; }); for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i) { var language = jQuery("#language-template").html(); var lang = langs[i]; language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang) .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user) .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link); language = jQuery(language); jQuery("#languages").append(language); } }</script>
```

Comment: 0 will diseapear when added to anything else

Comment: 0 is not relevant! Relevant output is between `1` and `9`!

Comment: Could you add some examples featuring no alphanumeric characters?

Comment: I mean something like `!@#$%^&*()`; something which should return `*`.

Comment: It has been very hard to resist citing this in some of the technical-analysis discussions on the Money area...  ;-p

Answer (score 6):

## Matlab, 121 bytes

```
s=[input('','s'),'*'];while nnz(s)>1;s=num2str(sum(mod([s(48<s&s<58)-4,s(96<s&s<123)+2,s(64<s&s<91)-2],9)+1));end;disp(s)
```

Matlab is just not made for strings =(

Comment: Hey, at least it isn't as verbose as Mma :P

Comment: my +1, I couldn't do better. btw, is it necessary to put `disp` statement?

Comment: @brainkz Maybe, but I usually incude it to [be on the safe side](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7369/how-do-we-treat-default-output-formats-such-as-ans-etc)

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, <s>174</s> <s>168</s> 163 bytes

```
Catch[#-9Floor[Max[#-1,1]/9]&@If[(a=Tr[Characters@#/.{(b=a_String)?DigitQ:>FromDigits@a,b?LetterQ:>LetterNumber@a~Mod~9,b->0}])<1&&#~StringFreeQ~"0",Throw@"*",a]]&
```

Does the first step, then computes the digital root.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>97</s> 74 characters

```ruby
n=->s{(t=eval s.tr('a-z9A-Z','1-9'*6).scan(/\d/)*?+)&&t>9?n[t.to_s]:t||?*}
```

Sample run:

```
2.1.5 :001 > n=->s{(t=eval s.tr('a-z9A-Z','1-9'*6).scan(/\d/)*?+)&&t>9?n[t.to_s]:t||?*}
 => #<Proc:0x00000001b4b3f0@(irb):4 (lambda)> 

2.1.5 :002 > puts ['13579', 'Hello, world!', '00 0 00', '!@#$%^&*();', ' ', '3.141592', '3.1415926535897932384', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Anna', 'Izis'].map{|s|'%s : %s'%[n[s],s]}
7 : 13579
7 : Hello, world!
0 : 00 0 00
* : !@#$%^&*();
* :  
7 : 3.141592
7 : 3.1415926535897932384
1 : Bob
2 : Charlie
3 : Anna
9 : Izis
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, <s>91 89 76</s> 74 bytes

73 + 1 for `-p` switch

```perl
s/[a-z]/(ord($&)%32-1)%9+1/eig;$t="*",s/\d/$t+=$&/eg,$_=$t until/^[*\d]$/
```

Tests

```shell
for test in '13579' 'Hello, world!' '00 0 00' '!@#$%^&*();' ' ' \
    '3.141592' '3.1415926535897932384' \
    Bob Charlie Anna Fana Gregory Denis Erik Helen Izis ;do  
    perl -pe '
      s/[a-z]/(ord($&)%32-1)%9+1/eig;$t="*",s/\d/$t+=$&/eg,$_=$t until/^[*\d]$/
      ' < <(echo -n "$test")
    echo "  $test"
done
```

```
7  13579
7  Hello, world!
0  00 0 00
*  !@#$%^&*();
*   
7  3.141592
7  3.1415926535897932384
1  Bob
2  Charlie
3  Anna
4  Fana
5  Gregory
6  Denis
7  Erik
8  Helen
9  Izis
```

Thanks @manatwork for helping me to save **<s>2 14 16 15</s> 17** chars!!

... I've thinked about: *`N % 32 + Y` may replace `( N & 31 ) + Y`*!

Comment: If you capture the whole matched substring, `$1` is equal with `$&`. So better remove the capturing and change the variable name.

Comment: @manatwork, Strange, I remember trying this before and use parenthesis while this not worked as expected... I don't understand/remember my previous tests (second `s/../../eg` use already `$&` finely)... Thanks anyway!

Comment: `while`'s block could be `$t="*";s/\d/$t+=$&/eg;$_=$t`.

Comment: Oh yes! I whipped this because of `Argument "*" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 2, <> line 1.`, but... Who care about `-w` switch?

Comment: Sorry, but its actually 1 character longer, as you should include the `-p` switch in the count.

Comment: Sorry again (this time a bigger sorry), but it fails on single non-word character input, for example “!” results the same ”!”. (_Seems_ to work because with here-string the input is always passed with a trailing  newline, so in your test cases never passes single character input. Use `echo -n "$test" | perl -pe '…'` to see what I mean.) You can solve it by changing the `while` condition to `!/^[\d*]$/`. While there, to reduce the score loss, you may replace the entire `while` with this: `$t="*",s/\d/$t+=$&/eg,$_=$t until/^[\d*]$/`.

Comment: There is one more improvement you can do. As `&` has lower precedence than `+`, while `%` has higher, change `&31` → `%32` and you can remove the parentheses around that subexpression.

Answer (score 3):

### ES6, 98 bytes

```
s=>(m=s.match(/[1-9a-z]/gi))?(t=8,m.map(c=>t+=c>'@'?c.charCodeAt()&31:+c),t%9+1):/0/.test(s)?0:'*'
```

Ungolfed:

```
function(s) {
    var m = s.match(/[1-9a-z]/gi);
    if (m) {
        var t = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            if (m[i] > '@')
                t += m[i].charCodeAt(0) & 31;
            else
                t += parseInt(m[i]);
        }
        return t % 9 || 9;
    }
    return /0/.test(s) ? 0 : "*";
}
```

94-byte version that only works on short strings:

```
s=>(m=s.match(/[1-9a-z]/gi))?m.map(c=>c>'@'?c.charCodeAt()&31:c).join``%9||9:/0/.test(s)?0:'*'
```

Using `match`, `map` and `join` turned out to be shorter than using `replace` twice:

```
s=>(m=s.replace(/[^1-9a-z]/gi,''))?m.replace(/[a-z]/gi,c=>c.charCodeAt()&31)%9||9:/0/.test(s)?0:'*'
```

Test it here: https://jsbin.com/zizosayisi/edit?js,console

Comment: This doesn't work for the input `00 0 00`

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Ah, the REPL I was using just prints `["0"]` as `0` so I couldn't tell the difference.

Comment: Much, much better than @rink.attendant.6 version! Clever golf hacks used. Could you explain `> '@'`, `& 31` and `|| 9`?

Comment: @Pavlo `> '@'` just distinguishes between letters and numbers. `& 31` is a useful way of ignoring the difference between upper and lower case character codes, as it also conveniently directly maps character codes into 1..26 values. `|| 9` is used because `% 9` returns 0 for multiples of 9 but repeatedly adding digits returns 9 for non-zero multiples of 9. In the golfed code I use `(t + 8) % 9 + 1` instead which comes to the same thing.

Comment: The language is commonly named "JavaScript (ES6)"

Answer (score 2):

## Gema, 161 characters

```
*=@n{*}
n:\A=@set{t;};<L1>=@set{t;@add{$t;@add{@mod{@sub{@mod{@char-int{$0};32};1};9};1}}};<D1>=@set{t;@add{$t;$0}};?=;\Z=@cmps{$t;;;\*;@cmpn{$t;9;$t;$t;@n{$t}}}
```

(Written only to try whether recursive domain calls work.)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ for input in '13579' 'Hello, world!' '00 0 00' '!@#$%^&*();' ' ' '3.141592' '3.1415926535897932384'; do
>     echo -n "'$input' : "
>     gema '*=@n{*};n:\A=@set{t;};<L1>=@set{t;@add{$t;@add{@mod{@sub{@mod{@char-int{$0};32};1};9};1}}};<D1>=@set{t;@add{$t;$0}};?=;\Z=@cmps{$t;;;\*;@cmpn{$t;9;$t;$t;@n{$t}}}' <<< "$input"
>     echo
> done
'13579' : 7
'Hello, world!' : 7
'00 0 00' : 0
'!@#$%^&*();' : *
' ' : *
'3.141592' : 7
'3.1415926535897932384' : 7
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 64 bytes

```
jk42ht`YUt'[a-z]'XXY}3+w'[1-9]'XXY}6+h,9X\st9>]w2Y24Y2h!=~?x'*']
```

This uses [current version (4.0.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/4.0.0) of the language.

I have a feeling that it could be made shorter...

#### Test cases

```
>> matl
 > jk42ht`YUt'[a-z]'XXY}3+w'[1-9]'XXY}6+h,9X\st9>]w2Y24Y2h!=~?x'*']
 > 
> 13579
7

>> matl
 > jk42ht`YUt'[a-z]'XXY}3+w'[1-9]'XXY}6+h,9X\st9>]w2Y24Y2h!=~?x'*']
 > 
> Hello, world!
7

>> matl
 > jk42ht`YUt'[a-z]'XXY}3+w'[1-9]'XXY}6+h,9X\st9>]w2Y24Y2h!=~?x'*']
 > 
> 00 0 00
0

>> matl 
 > jk42ht`YUt'[a-z]'XXY}3+w'[1-9]'XXY}6+h,9X\st9>]w2Y24Y2h!=~?x'*']
 > 
> !@#$%^&*();
*

>> matl
 > jk42ht`YUt'[a-z]'XXY}3+w'[1-9]'XXY}6+h,9X\st9>]w2Y24Y2h!=~?x'*']
 > 
> 3.141592
7

>> matl
 > jk42ht`YUt'[a-z]'XXY}3+w'[1-9]'XXY}6+h,9X\st9>]w2Y24Y2h!=~?x'*']
 > 
> 3.1415926535897932384
7

>> matl
 > jk42ht`YUt'[a-z]'XXY}3+w'[1-9]'XXY}6+h,9X\st9>]w2Y24Y2h!=~?x'*']
 > 
> Bob
1

>> matl
 > jk42ht`YUt'[a-z]'XXY}3+w'[1-9]'XXY}6+h,9X\st9>]w2Y24Y2h!=~?x'*']
 > 
> Charlie
2

>> matl
 > jk42ht`YUt'[a-z]'XXY}3+w'[1-9]'XXY}6+h,9X\st9>]w2Y24Y2h!=~?x'*']
 > 
> Anna
3

>> matl
 > jk42ht`YUt'[a-z]'XXY}3+w'[1-9]'XXY}6+h,9X\st9>]w2Y24Y2h!=~?x'*']
 > 
> Izis
9
```

Comment: Unfortunely, I could'nt test your sample. Please post whole test cases, including recently added tests (sorry).

Comment: @F.Hauri Yes, you'd need Matlab to test them. Sorry about that, no online compiler yet. I've added the test cases

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>162</s> <s>159</s> 157 bytes

```js
f=_=>{for(_=_.replace(/\W+/g,''),g=$=>''+[...$.toUpperCase()].reduce((p,a)=>isNaN(a)?p+(a.charCodeAt()-64)%9:+a+p,0);1<(l=_.length);_=g(_));return!l?'*':g(_)}
```

Still trying to look for a way to use implicit return in the outer function.

#### Ungolfed + unminified

```js
f = str => {
  str = str.replace(/\W+/g, '');
  recursiveFunc = $ => String([...$.toUpperCase()].reduce(
    (prev, val) => isNaN(val) ? prev + (val.charCodeAt() - 64) % 9 : Number(val) + prev,
    0
  ));
  while (1 < (len = str.length)) {
    str = recursiveFunc(str);
  }
  return len === 0 ? '*' : recursiveFunc(str)
}
```

1. Strips out all non-alphanumeric characters
2. Calls a function recursively to reduce the characters to their respective values while the string is longer than 1 character.

   1. Converts the string to uppercase to easily work with ASCII codes
   2. Convert to array using spread operator and run an accumulator
   3. Use the global `isNaN` function (which casts its input) to check if it's not a number

      - If it isn't, convert to ASCII code and mod 9 to get its respective value
      - If it is a number, cast it
3. If the length is 0, no alphanumeric characters were present (return an asterisk), otherwise return the output of the recursive function.

Comment: This break rule `00 0 00`, output `*` instead of  `0`!

Comment: @F.Hauri Fixed.

Comment: You can avoid explicit return by using comman operator: `_=>{expr;return expr}` => `_=>(expr,expr)`

Comment: @Pavlo How do I apply that in my case?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, throws SyntaxError: https://jsbin.com/havotusoqa/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 126 bytes

```
l x=[n|(c,n)<-zip(['0'..'9']++['a'..'z']++'\0':['A'..'Z'])$0:cycle[1..9],c==x]
g[]="*"
g[x]=show x
g x=f$show$sum x
f=g.(l=<<)
```

Usage: `f "Hello, world!"` -> `"7"`.

`l` is  a lookup table for characters to list of integers (singleton list, if char is found, empty list otherwise). `f` lookups every char of it's argument and flattens the returned list of lists into a simple list of integers and calls `g` to check the end condition (empty list (-> `*`) or single integer) or to call `f` with the sum of the list for another round.

Answer (score 1):

## Pure bash, <s>199</s> 194 bytes

```bash
eval a+={a..z};r="$1";while [ "${r:1}" ];do o=;for ((i=0;i<${#r};i++));do
l=${r:i:1};case $l in [a-zA-Z])d=${a%${l,}*};((o+=$((${#d}%9+1))));;[0-9])
((o+=l));;esac;done;r="$o";done;echo "${o:-*}"
```

(second line break is only for avoiding scrollbar)

Test rule:

```
numerology() {
    eval a+={a..z};
    r="$1";
    while [ "${r:1}" ]; do
        o=;
        for ((i=0; i<${#r}; i++))
        do
            l=${r:i:1};
            case $l in 
                [a-zA-Z])
                    d=${a%${l,}*};
                    ((o+=$((${#d}%9+1))))
                ;;
                [0-9])
                    ((o+=l))
                ;;
            esac;
        done;
        r="$o";
    done;
    echo "${o:-*}"
}

for test in '13579' 'Hello, world!' '00 0 00' '!@#$%^&*();' ' ' \
            '3.141592' '3.1415926535897932384'\
            Bob Charlie Anna Fana Gregory Denis Erik Helen Izis ;do
    echo "$(numerology "$test")" $test
done
```

```
7 13579
7 Hello, world!
0 00 0 00
* !@#$%^&*();
*
7 3.141592
7 3.1415926535897932384
1 Bob
2 Charlie
3 Anna
4 Fana
5 Gregory
6 Denis
7 Erik
8 Helen
9 Izis
```

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 50 bytes

```
,$ù;ú1╤▀+;#pX╗@-@-;Y`'*.`╬X1WX`╜í;s9*@%u`MΣ$;lDWX
```

Hex Dump:

```
2c24973ba331d1df2b3b237058bb402d402d3b5960272a2e7f
60ce5831575860bda13b73392a402575604de4243b6c445758
```

[Try It Online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=2c24973ba331d1df2b3b237058bb402d402d3b5960272a2e7f60ce5831575860bda13b73392a402575604de4243b6c445758&input=Hello,%20World!)

Explained:

```
,$ù                                               Read input, make it a string, lowercase
    ú                                             Push lowercase alphabet
     1╤▀+                                         Prepend base 10 digits.
         ;#pX╗                                    Remove "0" from a copy and stash in reg0
   ;          @-                                  Remove alphanumerics from input copy
                @-                                Remove nonalphanumerics from input
                  ;Y                              Push 1 if string is empty, else 0
                    `'*.`╬                        If top is truthy, output * and halt
                          X                       Discard boolean
                           1                      Push 1 to enter loop
                            WX                 WX Loop while top of stack is truthy
                              `         `M        Map this function over the string
                               ╜                  Push alphanumeric string from reg0
                                í                 Push index of this char in it
                                 ;s9*             Push 9 if found, else -9
                                     @%u          Take index mod previous: this yields the
                                                  correct conversion from the numerology
                                          Σ       Sum the resulting digits.
                                           $      Convert the sum to a string.
                                            ;lD   push 1 less than its length
```

Comment: @F.Hauri Click "Try It Online". enter your test cases in the input box.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 39 bytes

```
IK@J+jkUTGrz0WtK=K`smh%xtJd9-K\0)K).?\*
```

[Try It Online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=IK%40J%2BjkUTGrz0WtK%3DK%60smh%25xtJd9-K%5C0%29K%29.%3F%5C%2a&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=Hello%2C+World%21%0A00+0+00%0A%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26%2a%28%29%3B%0A3.141592%0A3.1415926535897932384%0ABob%0ACharlie%0AAnna%0AFana%0AGregory%0ADenis%0AErik%0AHelen%0AIzis&debug=0)

I'm just doing this because I can't sleep. Maybe I'll explain it tomorrow...

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 78 <s>83</s>

Recursive solution. Being tail recursion, the variables t and r have not to be local.

```js
f=x=>(t=r=0,x.replace(/\w/g,d=>t+=1+~-parseInt(d,r=36)%9),t>9?f(''+t):r?t:'*')
```

**Explained**

```js
f=x=>(
  t = 0, // set initial value of counter to 0 
  r = 0, // flag to verify that we found at last one alphanumeric chars
  x.replace(/\w/g, d => ( // execute the following for each alphanumeric character
    // t += 1 + ~-parseInt(d,r=36) % 9 explained below
    r = 36, // set flag, could be any nonzero value
    d = parseInt(d,36), // convert to numeric. a..z -> 10..25, case insensitive.
    d = 1 + (d-1) % 9, // this is the arithmetic conversion required (
                       // works also with 0 because the strange implementation of % in javascript for negative numbers
    t = t + d // add to global counter
  ) ), 
  t > 9 // if t > 9 then we found some alphanumeric char, but we must repeat the loop on t
    ? f(''+t) // recursive call, t is numeric and must become a string
    : r // check flag r 
      ? t // if alphanumeric found, return t 
      : '*' // else return '*'
)
```

**Test snippet**

```js
f=x=>(t=r=0,x.replace(/\w/g,d=>t+=1+~-parseInt(d,r=36)%9),t>9?f(''+t):r?t:'*')

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n';

;[['13579',7],['Hello, world!',7],['00 0 00',0],['!@#$%^&*();','*'],
['3.141592',7],['3.1415926535897932384',7],
['Bob', 1],['Charlie', 2],['Anna', 3],['Fana', 4],['Gregory', 5],
['Denis', 6],['Erik', 7],['Helen', 8],['Izis', 9]]
.forEach(t=>{
  i=t[0]+''
  k=t[1]
  r=f(i)
  console.log(i+' -> ' + r + (k==r? ' OK':' Fail - expected '+k))
  })
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 133 bytes

```
f[s_]:= ToCharacterCode@ToUpperCase@s-64/.{a_/;17>-a>6:>a+16,b_/;b<1||b>26:>""}//If[Or@@NumberQ/@#,Tr@#/.""->0//.a_:>Tr@IntegerDigits@a,"*"]&
```

A bit different from LegionMammal978's above. My function turns everything into a character code, then filters out the non-alphanumeric things (replacing them with empty strings). If there are no alphanumerics, then it returns *, otherwise it takes the digital root. This could be significantly (~15B) shorter if I didn't have to deal with the all-zeros-string case. C'est la vie.

Mathematica magic, for the uninitiated: `foo//.a_:>Tr@IntegerDigits@a` is a repeated replacement: it replaces any numbers `a` in foo with the sum of their digits, then it replaces again until it hits a fixed point, i.e. `a` stops changing under replacement.

**Tests:**

```
f /@ {"13579", "Hello,world!", "00 0 00", "!@#$%^&*()", "3.141592","3.1415926535897932384"}
     => {7, 7, 0, "*", 7, 7}
f /@ {"Bob", "Charlie", "Anna", "Fana", "Gregory", "Denis", "Erik",  "Helen", "Izis"}
     => {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Comment: Unfortunely, I could'nt test your sample. Please post test cases

Comment: On my way. While putting together the tests, I've also found some typos to fix. Thanks ;)